# Рефакторинг длины метода

Tags: java, методы, рефакторинг

Как можно сократить такой вот метод

```
public String format(DivisionResult divisionResult) {
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

// -------change-----------------------------
if (divisionResult == null || divisionResult.getDivisor() == 0) {
    return "";
}
if (divisionResult.getDividend() == 0) {
    return "0";
}
 // -------change-----------------------------
int[] multiplyResult = divisionResult.getMultiplyResult();
int[] remainderNumbers = divisionResult.getRemainderNumber();
int remainderElementLength = remainderNumbers.length;

for (int i = 0; i < remainderElementLength; i ++) {
    if (i == remainderElementLength - 1) {
        int indent = (remainderNumbers[i] != 0) ? 1 : 0;
        result.append(String.format("%" + (i + indent) + "s", remainderNumbers[i])).append("\n");
        break;
    }
    if (multiplyResult[i] != 0) {
        result.append(_formLastSection(remainderNumbers[i], multiplyResult[i], i));
    }
}

modify(divisionResult, result);
return result.toString();
}
```

Вроде как-то можно упростить блок if выделенный как --Change--, но я не могу понять как. Подойдут любые варианты

Comment: @SeniorPomidor откуда NPE если первое условие true дальше логическая операция не осуществляться

Comment: А почему решили, что нужно сделать рефакторинг?

Comment: требуют, чтобы методы не превышали 25 строк кода! Я только учусь. И сказали блок if можно заменить с помощью примерно такой строки StringBuilder result = checkBaseConditions(divisionResult), а как дальше я не пойму!

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что условие `if (i == remainderElementLength - 1) {` имеет смысл вытащить из цикла

```
int[] multiplyResult = divisionResult.getMultiplyResult();
int[] remainderNumbers = divisionResult.getRemainderNumber();
int lastRemainderElement = remainderNumbers.length - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < lastRemainderElement; i++) {
    if (multiplyResult[i] != 0) {
        result.append(_formLastSection(remainderNumbers[i], multiplyResult[i], i));
    }
}

int indent = (remainderNumbers[lastRemainderElement] != 0) ? 1 : 0;
result
  .append(String.format(
    "%" + (lastRemainderElement + indent) + "s%n",
    remainderNumbers[lastRemainderElement]
  ));

modify(divisionResult, result);
return result.toString();
```

Ну и должно выполняться условие `remainderNumbers.length > 0`